# How to exclude a list of PFUsers in a PFUser.query()?

Tags: swift, parse-platform

How to exclude a list of PFUsers in a PFUser query (in Swift)? I used to use

```
 query.whereKey("username", notEqualTo: PFUser.currentUser()!.username!)
```

to exclude the currentUser. The addition of username doesn't feel right and it gets messy if it is a list of PFUsers and I want to exclude (To create a list of usernames? feels not a good answer)

More importantly, what if this list of PFUsers is the key value as result of another PFQuery? How to achieve something like

```
PFUser.query.where ... doesNotMatchKey: "followedUser", inQuery: relationQuery)
```

Comment: You aren't you using pointers or relationships? Storing usernames and doing string comparisons isn't ideal.

Comment: Yes, I used pointer. What is the ideal way to directly exclude PFUsers instead of comparing usernames?

Comment: What about using `notContainedIn`? `query.whereKey("objectId", notContainedIn: arrayOfUserObjectIds)`

Comment: Then you have to create an array of ids, basically the same as comparing to an array of usernames. Also, the key issue is what if this array of users is result of another query? Can it be achieved with query inquery?